# Ant exec not executing commands in Hudson

Tags: windows, ant, windows-xp, continuous-integration, hudson

When I just run the snippet of the following from the command line in Windows XP, the Ant target executes as I expect. However, when I run it from Hudson (v1.398) it says the script completes fine, but it doesn't actually do anything. It does not run the AdminShellExec.exe at all. What am I doing wrong? I have tried this several different ways in the ant script too (without .txt file, do cmd.exe /C first, use arg line instead of redirector, etc...), but same issue.

```
 <target name="stop-model">
        <echo file="Script.txt">STOP model1 Force exit</echo>
            <exec executable="AdminShellExec.exe">
                <redirector input="Script.txt"></redirector>
            </exec>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have issues with the file paths. Try specifying the full path to all files.

e.g.

c:\myfolder\AdminShellExec.exe

c:\myfolder\Script.txt

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the basedir attribute in your build file

> basedir - the base directory from which
>   all path calculations are done. This
>   attribute might be overridden by
>   setting the "basedir" property
>   beforehand. When this is done, it must
>   be omitted in the project tag. If
>   neither the attribute nor the property
>   have been set, the parent directory of
>   the buildfile will be used.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html